# Pandas: Compare two data frames that have duplicates

Tags: pandas

I have two dataframes and one has duplicates. I would prefer to retain one of the duplicates in the output.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'col1' : ['M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'C','C','C'], 'col2' : [10.5,11.5,14,15.5,51,51,52]}) 
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'col1' : ['M', 'C', 'C'], 'col2' : [10.5, 51, 52]})
```

The preferred output is

```
M    11.5       
M    14    
M    15.5    
C    51
```

Since in df1 there two rows with 51 for C any merging operation removes or retains both rows.

Comment: Not seeing how your preferred output is achieved from your inputs... Could you explain further the logic you're applying here?

Comment: Looks to me as op wants to decrement number of unique tuple found in df1 by the number of those tuples found in df2. My guess.

Comment: Jon, df1 is the larger data set (Client) and  df2 is a subset which matches with a sub set of another larger data set Bank. Bank too has col2 but values won't match exactly with col2 of Client (match with minimum of differences). To make the problem worse each data sets have hundreds of duplicates. I will share the code once it is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine `concat` + `drop_duplicates`, there is new key I created by using `cumcount` for only remove the multiple row once per time

```
s=pd.concat([df1,df2],keys=['df1','df2'])

s.assign(cumcount=s.groupby([s.index.get_level_values(0),s.col1,s.col2]).cumcount()).\  
   drop_duplicates(keep=False).\
     reset_index(level=0,drop=True).\
       drop('cumcount',1)
Out[127]: 
  col1  col2
1    M  11.5
2    M  14.0
3    M  15.5
5    C  51.0
```

Comment: Works. Thank you, Wen.

Comment: @Selvan yw ~ : -) happy coding

Answer (score 1):

Using `Counter` from the `collections` library
This is making an assumption that OP wants to remove from the first dataframe the number of unique pairs found in the second.  See [Pandas: Compare two data frames that have duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49222039/pandas-compare-two-data-frames-that-have-duplicates/49222272#comment85447879_49222039)

```
from collections import Counter

pd.DataFrame(list(
    (Counter(map(tuple, df1.values)) -
     Counter(map(tuple, df2.values))).keys()
), columns=['col1', 'col2'])

  col1  col2
0    M  11.5
1    M  14.0
2    M  15.5
3    C  51.0

​
```